# UIDatePicker similar to one in Contacts app with a no-year date selection

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to remove the “year” of the date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169602/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-year-of-the-date-picker)

I am new to iOS and want to make an iPhone version of my desktop Birthdays app. To enter the birth date the user needs to be able to enter just the month and day sometimes, without the year. Contacts app does just this with a date picker that has the year column ending at the current year and then dotted line for entering the date without the year. I tried:

```
datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
```

But that just prevents the user from entering dates beyond the current date. I have been looking at many examples of date picker but see no way to do this. I could create a custom `UIPickerView` and populate three columns with `m/d/year` but don't think that can be localized as to the month names.

Any suggestions on selecting "no year" in the date picker would be much appreciated. How did Apple do it?

Comment: Thanks, rmaddy. I hadn't seen that one but it looks very promising. I would also need the year column but could hopefully add that and populate with an array of maybe 100 years to present, plus the "no year" choice. Thanks - I'll get back hopefully with a solution. Rob

Comment: You should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) requesting this functionality.