# Can Year Constraint removed from the native DatePicker in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I am Building an app and I want `DatePicker` to only Show Month and Day, but not the year. Since Native DatePicker shows Day, Month, Year. Can year be removed from the native `DatePicker` or is there any way by which we can let the `DatePicker` show only day and month and not year.Somebody's having any Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to remove the "year" of the date picker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169602/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-year-of-the-date-picker)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only available date picker modes are

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDatePickerMode) {
    UIDatePickerModeTime,
    UIDatePickerModeDate,
    UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
    UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
};`

So no, if you want to select an actual *date* the year component always shows. You could however, try to use a regular `UIPickerView` and update the amount of days in the first component whenever the month changes, although I would not recommend doing so.

What do you need the date picker without a year for, after all?