# using UIDatePicker with only day and month swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uidatepicker

I am making an app, uses `UIDatePicker` component. Everything works fine with the below code.

```
myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
```

My problem is here how to avoid the year column, days and months are the only data that i want to show in the component.

Like:

```
2 November
3 November
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407149/uidatepicker-show-only-month-and-day  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169602/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-year-of-the-date-picker

Comment: @B.S. yes i saw that so no solution?

Comment: I suggest to use UIPickerView with 2 columns (day & month) and manage it your self.

Comment: @HoaParis thanks , i just wondered if it is possible with the defaults

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky but if you don't have to deal with date formats and locale it may work for you.

Place the UIDatePicker inside a UIView and align all sides to the containing view's edges.   Then change the right side constraint from 0 to -100 (you may have to find a different number depending on the size you want to give it).

In the containing UIView's User Defined Runtime Attributes add a key named clipsToBounds, make it a Boolean and make sure it is checked.

This will hide the edge of the Date Picker that is aligned beyond the UIView's right side.

Make sure you set a minimum and maximum date for January 1st to December 31st of a specific year (so the user doesn't accidentally go outside that year and you don't have to deal with multiple years).