# Converting date from one format to other returns nil in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, date-format

I am trying to convert a date that come in "2017-12-05T00:00:00-0500" format to Dec 05 .For that I am using following code but it returns nil every time. I don't know what is wrong in this code.Kindly review the code and let me know my mistake.Any kind of guidance in this direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
 [dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"];
        NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:[dic valueForKey:@"weight_date"]];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@" YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:s"];
        NSString *st = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];
        NSLog(@"%@",st);
```

Comment: what the OP you get from here `NSDate *d`

Comment: Have you checked that `d` actually contains a converted date

Comment: It returns nil.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169602/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-year-of-the-date-picker check may be useful

Comment: @Prez that means your original format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ` is incorrect

Comment: Thanks every one for replying so promptly.I can mark only one answer as correct but actually every one is correct ,the date format was actually the root cause of getting nil.

Comment: @Prez For future use this link -> http://nsdateformatter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format is wrong i have made changes please check answer.

Check below code i have replace your dic with date that you have posted in question:

```
NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:@"2017-12-05T00:00:00-0500"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd"];
NSString *st = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];
NSLog(@"%@",st);
```

Comment: I didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:[dic valueForKey:@"weight_date"]];//@"2017-12-05T00:00:00-05:00"
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd"];
NSString *st = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];
NSLog(@"%@",st);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I tested ur code, I came to know that dtf is not returning a value d is nil

So format for dtf should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-SSSS
```

Then replace rest with this.

```
NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:[dic valueForKey:@"weight_date"]];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"MMM dd"];
NSString *st = [dtF stringFromDate:d];
NSLog(@"%@",st);
```